# Spreadsheet: find a cell keyed by date

Tags: spreadsheet, iwork-numbers

This is a question about Apple Numbers spreadsheet program.

Suppose I have two sheets: *Benchmark* and *Training*.  In the *Benchmark* sheet, I track a benchmark value over time:

```
| Date       | Benchmark |
| ---------- | --------- |
| 2017-12-25 |     120.3 |
| 2018-01-01 |     121.4 |
| 2018-01-08 |     123.0 |
```

In the *Training* sheet, I record training values, also keyed by date, that relate to the benchmark value:

```
                            v--- column I want

| Date       | Actual | ... % of Benchmark |
| ---------- | ------ |     -------------- |
| 2017-12-26 |  119.5 |             -0.66% |   (benchmark: 120.3)
| 2017-12-27 |  120.0 |             -0.25% |   (benchmark: 120.3)
| 2018-01-09 |  122.1 |             -0.73% |   (benchmark: 123.0)
```

In words, for each row of the *Training* sheet, I want to determine the benchmark value that was taken most recently as of the training entry.  On both 2017-12-26 and 2017-12-27, the most recent benchmark was as of 2017-12-25.  On 2018-01-09, the most recent benchmark became 2019-01-08.

Is there a name for this type of reference?  And how can I accomplish this in Apple Numbers?

Answer (score -1):

The `LOOKUP` function works for this.

In the *Training* sheet, use this formula to get the Benchmark value:

```
LOOKUP(A2, Benchmark::Table 1::Date, Benchmark::Table 1::Benchmark)

        ^
        \-- reference to the Date cell in your current row
```

The [Apple Numbers documentation for LOOKUP](http://help.apple.com/functions/mac/7.3/#/ffa597dc7b) is ambiguous about how this function behaves when the *search-for* value is not found, but in my testing, this function behaves just like its Excel counterpart.

The [Excel documentation for LOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) says:

> If the LOOKUP function can't find the lookup_value, the function matches the largest value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal to lookup_value.

And that's exactly what's needed here.